# Memory alignment of larger-than-one-address integral types

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I'm doing something where I have to interpret the values of raw memory addresses, and I'm trying to find how, essentially, larger than `int` integral types are stored.

For the sake of this argument, let's assume a 32 bit architecture, where register size is 32 bits, an int is 32 bits, and a long is 64 bits. Is there some rule of thumb or guideline about how the two register values are aligned?

Let's just get the "it depends on the architecture / OS / language" arguments out of the way. I'm aware that nothing in this area is remotely portable or standardized (indeed, intentionally not specified in standards). I'm just curious if there's a general pattern here. I won't shoot anyone, any answer may erase my hard drive, standard caveats. I'm just curious.

I'm familiar enough with e.g. struct packing and how the compiler will (usually) ensure that types are aligned correctly when they take less space than fits the address boundary - but what happens when they are larger than address boundaries?

I can see a couple of reasonable layouts:

Assuming we're using address `0x10` and `0x11` to store a `long` of value, I dunno, 99. I'll make up some terminology here: `lowint` is the least significant half of the long, and `highint` is the most significant half.

If the layout is `0x10 => lowint`, `0x11 => highint`, then a read of `0x10` would yield a consistent value if the type were either an `int` or `long` and doesn't overflow MAX_INT, which is a nice feature - `0x10` is "99" in either case. We also take up two addresses growing *upwards* of our base address. On the other hand, the low and high parts seem "reversed".

If the layout is `0x10 => highint`, `0x11 => lowint` then the high and low parts are in order, but a read of `0x10` will yield "99" if it were an int and "0" if it were a long - so some investigation into the following address `0x11` is needed to assume that we're dealing with one long, and not, say, two ints. We still grow upwards.

If the layout is `0x10 => lowint`, `0x0F => highint` then we've grown backwards (i.e. taken up a strange previous address to get our second int of storage), but our ints are in order and reads of `0x10` are consistent across data types. This seems the least likely to me, as it would totally screw with caches and data line reads, but still, it's another option.

So what is most likely? My gut tells me that option 2 - in-order high and low parts with two ints storage space - would be the most convenient for the hardware, but I'm not positive that this is true. Anyone out there with some anecdotal evidence for any layout?

Comment: Are you by chance not talking about alignment? The latter part of your post, which discusses the order of the components, basically describes [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking here is referring to [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess). It turns out that big-endian vs little-endian vs mixed-endian is a major issue in computer architecture. The first one you mentions (ie 0x10 as lowint) is known as little endian and the second one is big endian.

We do not need to confuse ourselves on the direction in which things are loaded If we load 16-bits from 0x10 then we will get two bytes from 0x10 and 0x11 no matter the endianess scheme. Pointers rarely point downwards, so your last example, in my experience, never occurrs.

Registers do matter because the way the processor interprets the high and low bytes (endianess) determines how it is stored in memory. In portable software that depends on specific data structures which are moved across architectures it is necessary to reverse the byte order when the endianess of the processor is different with that of the data structure it is manipulating.

Comment: OK, got it - I think I was perhaps being thrown by a packing issue. As per Wikipedia, the font of all knowledge: "The internal bit-, byte-, or word-ordering within such a register is normally not considered "endianness", despite the fact that some CPU instructions may address individual bits (or other parts) using various kinds of internal addressing schemes." So truly endianness is the answer, and how e.g. bytes are packed into ints is not _technically_ endianness, though I often see that as the example case to explain endianness: chars packed into an int: technically "byte ordering".

Comment: @Matt Correct endianess is much more general. Your question and my answer treat a specific case dealing with endianess. My last paragraph was referring specifically to my experience with several architectures which allow subaddressing of registers (eg AX has AL and AH in x86) and technically it is true that this is independent of endianess, though generally parallel.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some rule of thumb or guideline about how the two register
>   values are aligned?

Alignment (like endianess) is a memory issue. It is unrelated to registers

Comment: That's what I was attempting to refer to with "register values" - i.e. the value stored at what is pointed to by one register. I'm not sure if there's a more concise terminology for "the contents of what is stored at one register address"